# Where are the Windows Powershell NFS commands?

Tags: powershell, windows-10, nfs

I'm following the following tutorials on setting up NFS mapping on Windows 10, but am unable to get the Get-NFS* commands working:

https://stealthbits.com/blog/mounting-nfs-exports-unix-server/

What I have done so far:

1. Opened up Power Shell.  Running the version query shows the following:

```
PS C:\> $PSversionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.1645
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.1645
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

2. Installed NFS utilities as described in the tutorial:

`Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName ServicesForNFS-ClientOnly, ClientForNFS-Infrastructure -Online -NoRestart`

3. Ran `Get-NfsMappingStore`, which produces an error:

```
Get-NfsMappingStore : The term 'Get-NfsMappingStore' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-NfsMappingStore
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-NfsMappingStore:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Any idea what am I missing?

Comment: [Edit] the question and show which instructions you've followed, that there is a working NFS share and which command, exactly, you use.

Comment: Which version of PowerShell are you using?  I notice on my Win10 machine with the NFS Client that PS v5.1 and v7.2 show different cmdlets for this module.  I didn't dig any deeper, but there might be something revealing in the module files that might explain it (e.g. .NET compatibility).

Comment: @vonPryz, I've rephrased the question to describe the step-by-step process to reproduce the error

Comment: Run `Import-Module NFS` before calling `Get-NfsMappingStore`

Comment: Thanks @MathiasR.Jessen I'm getting a module not found error:
```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Import-Module NFS
Import-Module : The specified module 'NFS' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module
directory.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module NFS
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (NFS:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

Comment: This link suggests there's another way to access some of these commands:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.3.0?topic=clients-configuring-windows-user-name-mapping

Answer (score -1):

Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name Rsat.ServerManager.Tools~~~~0.0.1.0